# JUnit Test ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

How can I JUnit test the `getData` method because `getData` is a `ArrayList`.

I am not sure if I need to change something in the JUnit test class (e.g. add some library for `arrayList`)

Comment: ArrayList is in java.util why do you think you won't have this library in your test? Are you working in some special environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the question is not specific enough to answer fully, but anyway here's a suggestion of simple test that you can implement:

```
public class MicrophoneTest {

    private Microphone microphone;

    @Test
    public void testGetData(){
        microphone = new Microphone("test");
        ArrayList data = microphone.getData();
        assertNotNull(data);
        assertEquals(data.size(), 2); // 2 is the expected size    

    }

}
```

Comment: I am doing the above however I get this error -  The method getsize() is undefined for the type ArrayList

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in the code. There should be `data.size()` instead of `data.getSize()`.

Comment: It's worked thanks but I'm wondering what data.size() does in testing?

Comment: assertEquals(data.size(), yourExpectedListSize); - this should test if your data list has the size that you expect it to have.
It's just an example, because i don't know what exactly are you expecting of your code to do. But if you want to know more about JUnit tests i suggest reading - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_api.htm .

Comment: Thats perfect before my getdata array has a counter of 10 so it only reads in 10 values

Comment: if I want do see if the array list locates the correct filepath would it be something similar?

Comment: Well then you would need to refactor your class code. But it's a totally different topic. ;)

Comment: Since example shows no data being added, correct test would be `assertEquals(data.size(), 0)` or `assertTrue(data.isEmpty())`. If data had been inserted, a better test would be something like `assertEquals(data, Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"))`, so that the values of the list are also tested.

Comment: why do I get the following error -  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment.SensorTest.testGetData(SensorTest.java:49)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown